# How to ignore directories using :e in vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

how do you ignore directories like `.git` and `node_modules` when you type and autocomplete with `:e **/foo<TAB>` in vim? i really prefer no plugins, so this command is a nice alternative to a fuzzy finder plugin. preferably something i can put in `.vimrc` would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `set wildignore`:

`set wildignore=node_modules/**,.git/**`